# How to fix the left column and right column and center section scroll horizontally?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table and I have to set the left column and right column will be fixed and scroll only center content horizontally. I tried some code but it's not working properly. left column and right column showing fixed but that are not working properly. I updated my code here:

```css
 table { border-collapse:separate; border-top: 3px solid grey; }
    td {
        margin:0;
        border:3px solid grey; 
        border-top-width:0px; 
        white-space:nowrap;
    }
    div { 
        width: 600px; 
        overflow-x:scroll;  
        padding:30px;
        position: relative;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .headcol, .headcol_right {
        position:absolute; 
        width:5em; 
        top:auto;
        border-right: 1px #solid black; 
        border-top-width:3px;
        margin-top:-3px;
        overflow:hidden;
        background-color : red;
    }
    .headcol{
     left: 0;
    }
    .headcol_right {
 right:0;
    }
```

```html
<div>
<table border="1">
 <thead  class="bg-primary">
  <tr>
   <th class="headcol">Sr. No</th>
   <th>No</th>
   <th>Date</th>
   <th>Student Name</th>
   <th>Standard</th>
   <th class="headcol_right">Actions</th>
   </tr>
 </thead>

 <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td class="headcol">1</td>
    <td>NOV17-00002</td>
    <td>09-11-2015 13:48:53</td>
    <td>jkajsaskjkljlk</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td class="headcol_right"><a href="">edit</a></td>

  </tr>

    <tr>
    <td class="headcol">1</td>
    <td>NOV17-00002</td>
    <td>09-11-2015 13:48:53</td>
    <td>jkajsaskjkljlk</td>
    <td>X</td>
      <td class="headcol_right"><a href="">edit</a></td>

  </tr> 
 </tbody>
</table>
 </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it.

```css
table {
  border: 0;
  border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
            td {
                margin:0;
                border:3px solid grey; 
                border-top-width:0px; 
                white-space:nowrap;
                display: table-cell;
    
            }
            td, th{
             width: 15%;
            }
            .container-block { 
                width: 800px; 
              /*  padding:30px;*/
                position: relative;
                margin: 0 auto;
            }
            .headcol, .headcol_right {
                position: absolute;
                /*width: 5em;*/
                top: auto;
                border-top-width: 3px;
                overflow: hidden;
                background-color: red;
                border: 3px solid grey;
            }
            .headcol{
               left: -45px;
            }
            .headcol_right {
            right: 20px;
            }
            .table-block {
                  margin-left: 85px;
                  overflow-x: scroll;
                  width: 565px;
            }
```

```html
<div class="container-block">
        <div class="table-block">
        <table border="1">
            <thead>
            <tr>
   <th  class="headcol">Student Name</th>
   <th style="min-width: 75px;">Invoice No</th>
   <th>Invoice Date</th>
   <th>Standard</th>
   <th>Subjects</th>
   <th>Amount</th>
   <th>Discount</th>
   <th>Tax</th>
   <th style="min-width: 110px;">Invoice Amount</th>
   <th style="min-width: 118px;">Payment Method</th>
   <th class="headcol_right">Actions</th>
   </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                <tr>
       <td class="headcol"><input type="checkbox" name="name">Naren</td>
                        <td>00002</td>
                        <td>09-11-2015 13:48:53</td>
                        <td>X</td>
                        <td>maths</td>
                        <td>2500</td>
                        <td>100</td>
                        <td>10</td>
                        <td>15000</td>
                        <td>Cheque</td>
                        <td class="headcol_right"><a href="">edit</a></td>

                </tr>

                        <tr>
                        <td class="headcol"><input type="checkbox" name="name">Praveen</td>
                         <td>00002</td>
                        <td>09-11-2015 13:48:53</td>
                        <td>X</td>
                        <td>maths</td>
                        <td>2500</td>
                        <td>100</td>
                        <td>10</td>
                        <td>15000</td>
                        <td>Cheque</td>
                       <td class="headcol_right"><a href="">edit</a></td>

                </tr>   
                      <tr>
                        <td class="headcol"><input type="checkbox" name="name">Ajeet</td>
                        <td>00002</td>
                        <td>09-11-2015 13:48:53</td>
                        <td>X</td>
                        <td>maths</td>
                        <td>2500</td>
                        <td>100</td>
                        <td>10</td>
                        <td>15000</td>
                        <td>Cheque</td>
                        <td class="headcol_right"><a href="">edit</a></td>

                </tr>


                         <tr>
                        <td class="headcol"><input type="checkbox" name="name">Amit</td>
                        <td>00002</td>
                        <td>09-11-2015 13:48:53</td>
                        <td>X</td>
                        <td>maths</td>
                        <td>2500</td>
                        <td>100</td>
                        <td>10</td>
                        <td>15000</td>
                        <td>Cheque</td>
                        <td class="headcol_right"><a href="">edit</a></td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
       <td class="headcol"><input type="checkbox" name="name">Naren</td>
                        <td>00002</td>
                        <td>09-11-2015 13:48:53</td>
                        <td>X</td>
                        <td>maths</td>
                        <td>2500</td>
                        <td>100</td>
                        <td>10</td>
                        <td>15000</td>
                        <td>Cheque</td>
                        <td class="headcol_right"><a href="">edit</a></td>

                </tr>

                        <tr>
                        <td class="headcol"><input type="checkbox" name="name">Praveen</td>
                         <td>00002</td>
                        <td>09-11-2015 13:48:53</td>
                        <td>X</td>
                        <td>maths</td>
                        <td>2500</td>
                        <td>100</td>
                        <td>10</td>
                        <td>15000</td>
                        <td>Cheque</td>
                       <td class="headcol_right"><a href="">edit</a></td>

                </tr>   
                      <tr>
                        <td class="headcol"><input type="checkbox" name="name">Ajeet</td>
                        <td>00002</td>
                        <td>09-11-2015 13:48:53</td>
                        <td>X</td>
                        <td>maths</td>
                        <td>2500</td>
                        <td>100</td>
                        <td>10</td>
                        <td>15000</td>
                        <td>Cheque</td>
                        <td class="headcol_right"><a href="">edit</a></td>

                </tr>


                         <tr>
                        <td class="headcol"><input type="checkbox" name="name">Amit</td>
                        <td>00002</td>
                        <td>09-11-2015 13:48:53</td>
                        <td>X</td>
                        <td>maths</td>
                        <td>2500</td>
                        <td>100</td>
                        <td>10</td>
                        <td>15000</td>
                        <td>Cheque</td>
                        <td class="headcol_right"><a href="">edit</a></td>

                </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: Your code is working and there is one issue. if you notice that there is some space between TH tag and TD tag which is fixed

Comment: you can set border-spacing: 0; for table. Add this in your css file,         table {border-spacing: 0;}

Comment: Please check this jsfiddle. I am getting the space between th and td. http://jsfiddle.net/Narendra2015/cywcfa2h/2/

Comment: Yes, I need like this.Please update your answer. Can we give the space between TH and TD tag ?

Comment: I have update the code based on your question. Please refer it, let me know if it work.

Comment: Yes, It's working perfectly for me.I just want to know can we add some space  I mean padding-bottom: 50px I have to display records below of the header

Comment: Just try line height for th {
    line-height: 50px;
}

Comment: Thanks for the reply. line-height is not working for me. Thanks for the help. upvote from my side.

Answer (score 0):

You need left-div and right-div that would be fixed and a center-table that would be scrollable horizontally.

You can you this jquery library to make the kind of UI that you need - 
https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/examples/initialisation/left_right_columns.html

It provides settings to fix left columns/ right columns -

1. fixedColumns.rightColumns
2. fixedColumns.leftColumns

Comment: Thanks for the reply. but don't want to use any plugin. I need pure CSS

Comment: You can inspect element the UI and get an idea how to implement it. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Can this example meet your need?

```css
table { 
border-collapse:separate; border-top: 3px solid grey; }
    td {
        margin:0;
        border:3px solid grey; 
        border-top-width:0px; 
        white-space:nowrap;
    }
    .wrap { 
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .inner {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 80px;
      right: 80px;
      overflow: auto;
    
    }
    .headcol, .headcol_right {
        position:fixed; 
        width:5em; 
        top:auto;
        border-right: 1px #solid black; 
        border-top-width:3px;
        margin-top:-3px;
        overflow:hidden;
        background-color : red;
    }
    .headcol{
     left: 0;
    }
    .headcol_right {
 right:0;
    }
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
<div class="inner">
<table border="1">
 <thead  class="bg-primary">
  <tr>
   <th class="headcol">Sr. No</th>
   <th>No</th>
   <th>Date</th>
   <th>Student Name</th>
   <th>Standard</th>
   <th class="headcol_right">Actions</th>
   </tr>
 </thead>

 <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td class="headcol">1</td>
    <td>NOV17-00002</td>
    <td>09-11-2015 13:48:53</td>
    <td>jkajsaskjkljlk</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td class="headcol_right"><a href="">edit</a></td>

  </tr>

    <tr>
    <td class="headcol">1</td>
    <td>NOV17-00002</td>
    <td>09-11-2015 13:48:53</td>
    <td>jkajsaskjkljlk</td>
    <td>X</td>
      <td class="headcol_right"><a href="">edit</a></td>

  </tr> 
 </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
 </div>
```